# Kafka Consumer weird consuming time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream

I have seen an issue with time when messages occurred on topic and consuming time.
I don't have a consumer lag which can have an impact on that but in logs:

> The following partitions still have unstable offsets

I restarted a few time application and for some time works fine but problems still occurred.

Why is doing that? What is the problem?

Comment: Please share your code and config as a [mcve]

Comment: This is a simple use case in the spring cloud function nothing more. The code doesn't matter in this case, because is simple consumer of data without additional I/O. 

Problem is a think maybe with brokers or something on producer side but others micros doesn't have a issue with the same data and the same topics.

Comment: But it does matter. Your error could be related to your config. Or the version of Spring Cloud you're using (which is what)? Please [edit] your question to include this information